# How to use web.reg_save_param() Java Web Vuser function to capture the response?

Tags: loadrunner

I am using  web.custom_request() Java Web Vuser function to send a request to server. Now I want to know how can I capture the response in my Vuser script?

I am not able to successfully do it using  web.reg_save_param() Java Web Vuser function.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thank you
Chaitanya

Comment: Please post some code showing what's not working, this will help others answer your question

Comment: I too would like to see what did *not* work. You found a solution, which looks not very exciting since it is exactly the documented way to do it. The excitement would be to see your previous attempts in comparison to the solution so everyone can learn from your mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself.

I used the following piece of code:

```
web.reg_save_param("Response",new String []{"LB=","RB=","LAST"});
...
...
...
 String response = lr.eval_string("<Response>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of your second statement: 
"String response = lr.eval_string("");"

The parameter is already stored as a string. You can use lr.eval_string to use it anywhere down the line.

Comment: Well fetching the result parameter's value into a local variable once and referencing the local variable is better than using lr.eval_string on every occasion where you want to reference the value because lr.eval_string is quite expensive (it allocates a string buffer which is kept until the iteration ends), I think.